# Runtime Error of too much memory used?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int X = 200;
    float Y = 1500;
    printf("Enter your initial Balance and the Amount to be Withdrawn. Note the Values should lie between 0 and 2000");
    scanf("%d", "%e", &X, &Y);
    if ((0 < X < 2000) && (0 < Y < 2000)) {
        if ((X < Y) && (X % 5 == 0)) {
            Y = Y - X;
            Y = Y - 0.5;
        } else {
            printf("%f", Y);
        }
        printf("%f", Y);
    } else {
        printf("The Input is Wrong");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Code basically asks for some number X. Subtracts it from Y and an additional amount 0.5 from Y. We have to give the as Y.
The Code is giving Runtime Error which could possibly be due to More Memeory than allowed being used.
Can anyone give any tips on how to reduce memory usage or see if there is an error in the program?

Comment: This program should not be producing any messages like that; it hardly uses any memory at all.  Can you give us the exact error message you're getting and what line you're getting it on?

Comment: That indentation is a work of art.

Comment: @James McLaughlin [NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: @James McLaughlin - you spoiled a work of art! Shame on you ;)

Comment: Actually, it is running fine. But the site, Iam giving it to is not accepting it.

Comment: To check for memory problems try using valgrind's memcheck tool. If you're on Linux: `sudo apt-get install valgrind` to install. Then run `valgrind --tool=memcheck ./executable_name parameters_list`. I'm sure this is not a memory problem, though.

Comment: @paulsm4 Aw, what can I say? I'm a philistine. :-(

Comment: No, Iam not on Linux. Can't you gents check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is homework...

... but this example might help clarify a few things:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    int new_balance, old_balance;
    float withdrawal;

    /* Get input */
    printf("Enter your initial Balance and the Amount to be Withdrawn.\n");
    printf("Note the values should lie between 0 and 2000\n");
    while (scanf("%d %f", &old_balance, &withdrawal) != 2) {
      printf ("please enter two valid floating point numbers\n");
    }

    /* Validate input */
    if ( (old_balance < 0.0) || (old_balance > 2000.0) ) {
      printf ("error: balance(%d): must be between 0.0 and 2000.0\n",
        old_balance);
      return 1;
    }
    if ( (withdrawal < 0.0) || (withdrawal > 2000.0) ) {
      printf ("error: withdrawal(%f): must be between 0.0 and 2000.0\n",
        withdrawal);
      return 1;
    }

    /* Compute balance */
    new_balance = old_balance - withdrawal;

    /* Print results */
    printf ("Withdrawal: %f; old balance: %d, new balance: %d.\n",
      withdrawal, old_balance, new_balance);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not at all sure what the requirement was with the "0.5" stuff, so I left it out.  My guess is that you wanted to "round up to the nearest dollar".  In which case "%" is definitely *not* the way to do it.

The original program might have compiled - but it almost certainly wasn't "correct".

And the original program, as far as I could tell, should have run just about anywhere - I didn't see anything likely to cause an "out of memory condition".

'Hope that helps .. at least a little...

Answer (score 2):

```
     scanf("%d,%e", &X, &Y);
```

Comment: Ok, so i have to take inputs in different scanf() functions?

Comment: int scanf(const char *format, ...);
So, first parameter is the format. You pass first, and second parameter as the format, then you would like to read your float into a "%e" string.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/stdio.h/scanfreadinput.htm

Answer (score 1):

(apart from the scanf() with the double format string, which has been handled by others)

```
if ((0 < X < 2000) && (0 < Y < 2000)) {
```

That does not work this way is C. You could try:

```
if (X > 0 && X < 2000 && Y > 0 && Y < 2000) {
```

Also note that you don't need the extra parentheses.
The same for the other line

```
if ((X < Y) && (X % 5 == 0)) {
```

Which could be:

```
if (X < Y && X % 5 == 0) {
```

Sometimes the rules of precedence are not that bad at all...